# Apache POI 3.10 autoSizeColumn fails

Tags: java, awt, apache-poi

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Font
        at java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(TextLayout.java:468)
        at java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:527)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:208)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:386)
```

My env is the following:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

nogui and java.awt.headless=true flags are not set.

Comment: Which OS do you use? Did you tried to reinstall JDK? Also find rt.jar and check if it contains java.awt.Font class.

Comment: You either need to run it headless, or run it under a GUI. Either one will work. Neither won't...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Apache POI QuickGuide entry on "How to adjust column width to fit the contents"](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Autofit):

> **Warning**
>
> To calculate column width Sheet.autoSizeColumn uses Java2D classes that throw exception if graphical environment is not available. In case if graphical environment is not available, you must tell Java that you are running in headless mode and set the following system property: java.awt.headless=true

You've said you're running neither in a graphical environment, nor with headless. As the quick guide makes clear, if you want to do graphical things (such as sizing fonts), you *must* run with either a graphical environment *or* headless enabled